# Setting PFObject in to UILabel

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I have created a PFObject named UserInfo. Everything saves to Parse correctly, but when I go to retrieve it I keep getting errors. Here  is my code below.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserInfo"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:currentUser];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    } else {
        self.userInfo = objects;
        NSLog(@"%@", self.userInfo);

        self.locationDisplay.text = [self.userInfo valueForKey:@"location"];

    }
}];
```

The NSLog out put for the error is as follows:

```
-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9aa2be0
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Activate Exception breakpoints and start debugging. The log message says it all, you are trying to query the length of an array that does not exist or is not an array at all. Can have multiple reasons.

Comment: That's strange because when I log the array that contains the objects it shows "<UserInfo:qEKo5YNIrZ:(null)>  {location = \"Orlando, FL"\ }

Comment: Are you sure the error's occurring from code within the block? And are you sure "location" is a string in your database?

Comment: @LyndseyScott yes 100% positive it is saved as "location" that's why I'm so confused, even when I use self.locationDisplay.text = [[PFUser currentUser] valueForKey:@"location"]; It doesn't give me an error, but instead nothing shows up. When I log the self.locationDisplay.text it comes up as (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBLock:` stores an array in `objects`.

Once this is done, you set your attribute `userInfo` to point to this array with the line

```
self.userInfo = objects;
```

So basically here, `self.userInfo` holds a reference to an array.

When you try to set your label, you call the method `valueForKey:` directly on the array. I believe you want to call this method on an object inside this array.

What you could try is change the line to :

```
self.locationDisplay.text = [[self.userInfo firstObject] valueForKey:@"location"];
```

which will look for the value for the key `@"location"` on the first object of your array, which should be a `PFObject`.

Note : you should first test that `objects` is not an empty array before calling this line, otherwise you may try to call `valueForKey:` on a `nil` object, if the array is empty.

Comment: worked perfectly with [[self.userInfo firstObject] valueForKey:@"location"]; Thanks!