# Can't Display Parse data in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm new to iOS programming and I'm trying to display Parse data in a collection view. I'm trying to display the string in a key to the collection view cell's label. I'm grabbing the "Folders" in `viewWillAppear:` but can't seem to get them displayed in the label. My code is below.

```
@interface FoldersViewController ()

@end

@implementation FoldersViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
        NSLog(@"current user %@", currentUser.username);
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
    }
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Folders"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"folderName"];
    [query orderByAscending:@"folderName"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        } else {
            // We found folders
            self.folders = objects;
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
            NSLog(@"Retrieved %d folders", (int)[self.folders count]);
        }
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.folders count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *folder = [self.folders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    titleLabel.text = (NSString*)self.folders;

    [collectionView reloadData];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting PFObject in to UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142060/setting-pfobject-in-to-uilabel)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the label's text to the folder (and whatever property of the folder you want to show), not the array:

```
titleLabel.text = folder
```

Also, it's not necessary to call reloadData in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to display the cells by connecting my cell's label with an IBAction Collection instead of a regular IBAction. I'm trying to build a note taking app and the only issue is each cell just says "Label" instead of the folder name that is saved on Parse. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
@interface FoldersViewController ()

@end

@implementation FoldersViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser) {
    NSLog(@"current user %@", currentUser.username);
} else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Folders"];
[query whereKeyExists:@"folderName"];
[query orderByAscending:@"folderName"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    } else {
        //We found folders
        self.folders = objects;
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"Retrieved %d folders", (int)[self.folders count]);
    }
}];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.folders count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

FolderCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UILabel *folder = (UILabel *)self.folders;

cell.folderTitle = (NSArray *)folder;


return cell;

}
```